# Submit form on radio button select in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have several radio button forms which are submitting data to my backend nicely when i hit the return key. However I want each form to submit and move to the next component/form as soon as a radio button is selected. Is there a way to submit a form and move to the next component on radio button selection?
Can onselect be used here, and if so how do i go about using it?

Here's my code:

```
export class ChoiceOne extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: null
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        const colourType = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            colourType
        });
    };


    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const typeOneItem = {
            time: new Date().toLocaleString("en-gb"),
            typeOne: this.state.colourType
        };
        firebase.writeTo(`${firebase.getCurrentUser().uid}/typeOne`, typeOneItem);
        this.props.onChosen(1);
    }

    render() {
            const colour = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green'];
            return (

                    <
                    div className = "type1" >
                    <
                    div className = "content" >
                    <
                    form onSubmit = {
                        this.handleSubmit
                    } >

                    {
                        colour.map((colour, index) =>
                            <
                            label key = {
                                index
                            } > {
                                colour
                            } <
                            input value = {
                                colour.toUpperCase()
                            }
                            checked = {
                                this.state.colourType === colour.toUpperCase()
                            }
                            onChange = {
                                this.handleChange
                            }
                            type = "radio" / >
                            <
                            /label>
                        )
                    } <
                    input type = "submit"
                    hidden / >
                    <
                    /form> < /
                    div > <
                    /div>
```

Answer (score 1):

call your `handleSubmit` function from the `handleChange` function

for example in the `handleChange function that is called every time a radio button is selected

```
handleChange = (e) => {
        const colourType = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            colourType
        });

        if(//check if you are ready to submit) {
            this.handleSubmit();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    };

handleSubmit() {
        const typeOneItem = {
            time: new Date().toLocaleString("en-gb"),
            typeOne: this.state.colourType
        };
        firebase.writeTo(`${firebase.getCurrentUser().uid}/typeOne`, typeOneItem);
        this.props.onChosen(1);
    }
```

you can use onselect but since you already have a onchange here it would be more efficient to use that!

Answer (score 0):

Either you can do conditional rendering, by rendering the specific component on after successfull `setState`, for that you have to create the components you needed and you can use the `props` call back to set the data in the parent. Or you can keep an iterartor and do multiple returns inside the same component.